# R - BATS and MSTS model non stationary

Tags: r, bats

I can't find any information about it, and I've tried both solutions and they seem to work.
But i have to differentiate the series (if not stationary) before using bats or msts?

Answer (score 1):

`msts` is a *data type* for multiply seasonal time series, it is not a model.

BATS, as implemented in the `bats()` function, is a forecasting model for multiple or complex seasonality. Time series that exhibit *any* kind of seasonality are *by definition* nonstationary, because their mean varies. BATS is explicitly aimed at treating this kind of nonstationarity.

This also illustrates that there are multiple "kinds" of nonstationarity, and that differentiating is not a cure-all. After all, if you differentiate a multiply seasonal time series, the result is still seasonal, and therefore nonstationary.

Comment: Ok thanks. For msts Is a typo, i mean mstl method. But i think Is the same for bats.

Comment: `mstl()` actually does not fit anything, it just decomposes the time series in a very empirical way. I am not aware of any distributional or stationarity assumptions for MSTL to have any particular properties. But you are right that it is explicitly intended for multiply seasonal time series, so it again will certainly not require stationarity.